# rewrite folder to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Sorry for this basic question but dealing with apache is a long time ago.
A subfolder has moved from `/download` to `/images/download`.
I now like to rewrite it in .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/download/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/download/images$
RewriteRule (.*) /images/download/$1 [R=302,L]
```

I would expect that

`http://example.com/download/literatur/a/online.pdf`

would be rewritten to

`http://example.com/images/download/a/online.pdf`

but it is not. Rewrite in general is working (mod_rewrite is enabled). What do I oversee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 1st rewrite condition is making your rule always fail because URI is not just `/download` it is actually `/download/<whatever-else>`.

You can use this rule instead in site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^download/ /images%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NC,NE]
```

This rule will match any URI that starts with `/download/` and will redirect this request to `/images/<URI>`